# Prevent from executing tasks in same time

Tags: swift, semaphore, grpc

I need advices about how to handle the oauth2 token refreshing in my app.

I'm using GRPC to make my http requests to my API which I'm connected with an oauth2 token (it expires after 1 hour).

Before launching every request, I check the token:

- Up-to-date ? launch networkRequest
- Out-dated ? launch refreshToken -> launch networkRequest

Everything seems to work well but in some cases, my client "lose" the token.

The problem is that for 2 requests A & B launched **in the exact same time**, if the token is outdated, they will both refresh it.
My server will generate a newTokenA, return it, generate newTokenB (remove newTokenA), return it.
If the response **newTokenA** arrives to the client **after newTokenB**, the client token token will not be the good one.

I used a **Semaphore** to ensure that one call the refreshToken is made at the same time.

But when my Semaphore is waiting, I don't receive any response from my server.

```
let semaphore: dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

func authenticate(completion: (GRPCProtoCall) -> (Void)) -> GRPCProtoCall {

    // Wait here if authenticate already called
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

     // If token up to date
    if isOAuth2TokenValid() {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) // Release semaphore
        completion(self.withAuthorization())
        return self
    }

    // Refresh the outdated token
    APIClient.shared.oAuth2AccessTokenRefresh { (response) -> (Void) in
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)  // Release semaphore
        completion(self.withAuthorization())
    }

    return self
}
```

Comment: Maintain a queue (can execute requests serially) for the token refreshing as soon as someone comes with a new request, if the count is greater than one ideally you are already fetching the token so don't process the new request.

Comment: For what it's worth, the https://github.com/p2/OAuth2 Swift framework will do that for you (disclosure: I'm the repo maintainer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)` holding your thread, you can try it with timeout incase last request does not response, and put it before return self

```
while semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.now() + Double(5000000000) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)) == DispatchTimeoutResult.success {//time out set to 5 seconds
    print("wait")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the semaphore was holding the thread and then, this thread could not receive any response from my server !

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to create the semaphore for `1` resource, not for `0` (which is used for reading purposes):

```
let semaphore: dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
```

Secondly, I think the problem is that you first release the semaphore, and then call the completion block: Do something like this:

```
// Refresh the outdated token
APIClient.shared.oAuth2AccessTokenRefresh { (response) -> (Void) in
    completion(self.withAuthorization())
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)  // Release semaphore at very end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not making the method entirely asynchronous? (`self` seems to be known anyway)

```
func authenticate(completion: (GRPCProtoCall) -> ()) {

    // If token up to date
    if isOAuth2TokenValid() {
        completion(self.withAuthorization())
    } else {
    // Refresh the outdated token
        APIClient.shared.oAuth2AccessTokenRefresh { response in
           completion(self.withAuthorization())
        }
    }
}
```